# Reuse a custom WordPress menu on another WordPress website

Tags: menus, rest-api, navigation, import

My WordPress website consists of two separate WordPress installs (one lives in a subdirectory). From a visitor's perspective it feels like one single website. To achieve this I had to manually replicate the navigation menu of install A in install B.

Since we have a lot of changes on our website, we are looking for a solution that reads the custom menu from install A (preferrably over the REST API) and displays it as a custom menu in install B. Is there a way to achieve this easily?

Comment: If you do make a remote request, you'll want to cache it, for at least an hour. Or, cache ti forever then make the site ping the other site when the menu changes to fetch an updated copy.